# Azure VM run-command fails with piped commands

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to install Azure CLI on an ubuntu VM running in Azure.
I am using the run-command cli operation to execute the command
`az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name  trainingVM-1 --resource-group azure-privsec --scripts "curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash"`

When running a non-piped command, the command works fine but when I run the above piped command to install azure-cli, it fails with the error:
`Could not retrieve credential from local cache for service principal 8bf34d22-7230-47e7-907e-e0df201xxxxx. Please run 'az login' for this service principal.`

One of the reasons could be that I am using an old version of Azure cli(2.29.2). For now, I dont have the leverage to upgrade the azure-cli version.
What can be the best way to install `azure-cli` on my VM using the `run-command` cli call.

Edit:
Splitting into two commands like this works for me but I am still trying to see if we can consolidate it into a single command:

`az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name  trainingVM-1 --resource-group azure-privsec --scripts "wget -O /tmp/file.sh  https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb"`

`az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name  trainingVM-1 --resource-group azure-privsec --scripts "sudo bash /tmp/file.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Azure PowerShell and Azure DevOps pipeline, your first Azure VM run-command run successfully.

1. Use [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-9.1.0), I can run this command directly without any issue.
   [image]
2. Use [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) in the DevOps pipeline and use a [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).
   Please ensure that the service principal corresponding to the Azure Resource Manager connection(Service Connection) has sufficient permission for your Azure VM, such as owner or contributor permissions.
   [image]
   Then I can see the command run successfully.
   [image]

There are some docs for your reference:

[Manage service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection)

[Connect to Microsoft Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)